# Discover the roaming carrier on Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to know the roaming carrier on Android?

I know getNetworkOperatorName() returns the carrier name, but it gets the name from the IMSI, and this carrier might not be the one used when the person is on roaming.

Comment: This might help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/ASVpv7RbLL8

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/ASVpv7RbLL8)?

I think [this part might help you](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/ASVpv7RbLL8/hRYtSerT3RAJ).

> Here are the interesting GSM functions in Android:
>
> `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()` 
>       Returns the home operator (MCC + MNC). It just returns the first  part of the IMSI stored on the SIM.
>
> `ServiceState.getOperatorNumeric()` 
>       Returns the current operator (MCC + MNC). This is retrieved from  the current cell site.
>
> `GsmCellLocation.getLac()` 
>       Returns the Location Area Code of the current cell site.
>
> `GsmCellLocation.getCid()` 
>       Returns the Cell ID of the current cell site.
>
> Some of these have CDMA equivalents:
>
> `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()` 
>       In non "world phones", this returns the first 6 digits of the IMSI  (e.g. 3100004). This is bogus, because CDMA IMSI's have 00 for the MNC
>   which 2 digits not 3 and useless either way. The 4 on the end is 
>   actually the beginning of the subscriber ID. This is a bug in Android 
>   as far as I can tell. In world phones, it will probably return the MCC
>
> +MNC for an operator in Europe.
>
> `ServiceState.getOperatorNumeric()` 
>       Returns the MCC + 00. This is mostly useless, because it does not  identify the carrier.
>
> `CdmaCellLocation.getSystemId()` 
>       Returns the System ID of the current cell cite (this identifies  the operator that owns the cell site). It is analogous to MNC.
>
> `CdmaCellLocation.getNetworkId()` 
>       Returns the Network ID of the current cell site. It is analogous  to LAC.
>
> `CdmaCellLocation.getBaseStationId()` 
>       Returns the Base Station ID of the current cell site, It is  analogous to CID.
>
> What is missing is a CDMA equivalent of
>   `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator  ()` that returns the home SID.